# Url error in local host image address

Tags: php, mysql

[Everything is ok in external url but in internal src file gives error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3jQz.png)

```
      '<th><a href="presentation_add.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">+</button></a></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                    $lastwork="luckyassigment/frontend/images/products/prod_large.jpg";

                 ?> 
                <tr class="bg_hover">
                    <td><?php echo $row['product_name'] ?></td>
                    <td><img src="localhost/luckyassigment/frontend/images/products/prod_large.jpg" alt="Nahi hy" width="150"></td>
                    <td class="updates_section"><a href=""><img src="assest/css/img/edit.png" alt="edit"></a>&nbsp <a href=""><img src="assest/css/img/delete.png" alt="Delete"></a></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </div>'
```

Comment: Which one of the URLs is not working? How is your file structure? Please provide as much information on the error as possible. At first glance, I'd say you made a typo: "assest" --> "assets"

Answer (score 0):

That error means that there's no image with that name where the link is pointing to.

Probably the error is in the URL you passed in the src of the img, double check it (e.g. Could it be that it is 'assignment' instead of 'assigment'?).

If you can't find the error, check the developer console to see the message error and understand what's the problem.